# Labeling objects in a sequence of imahes - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I have a sequence of images (video frames). I need to identify the objects as they move (and also some leave the region of interest or new ones appear in the region of interest). By using bwlabel the object to the left of the region of interest is always object 1, but i want to maintain the numbering of the objects as they appear in time (and move out of the region of interest). When one or more objects move out of the region of interest I still want the other objects to have the labeling as if that object was still there. In addition the objects change size throught time. For better clarity I'm attaching a sketch of what i want to achive.

[image: Sketch of the result i want to achieve]

Does anybody have any tips/sugesstions or knows about a function that does this (i was not able to find any)?

Comment: are you looking for programs/libraries that do this? or are you prepared to write code? if you're looking for an approach, first you need to have detections, and then you can associate detections to "objects" with identity that you track (nearest euclidean distance would be okay) over time

Comment: Either, or. If a library that does this already exist i'd gladly use it, otherwise i'll write the code. I already performed detections the main problem now is how to determine objects as described and save the geometry.